# Bounding an integral between two expressions

Tags: integration

The problem asks to prove that

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+4n+8}}{n+2}\le \displaystyle\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+t^n} dt \le \dfrac{n+4}{n+2}$$

holds for all $n$ in  $\mathbb{N}^*$

It's from a local Highschool assignment, I tried many ways but the boundings I get aren't the required ones.

For the right inequality, I tried using MVT writing the integrand as $f(t) - f(0) $ where $f:t \mapsto \sqrt{1+t^n}$ but that didn't work

Comment: Hint for the RHS inequality. Use the fact that $\sqrt{a+b} \le \sqrt a +\sqrt b$.

Comment: I wonder why the question has been blocked.
I posted (in an edit) the original document), my tries gave no interesting result.
The left inequality seems not obvious

Comment: I do agree with you. Maybe explaining more in details what you tried? *Closers*, an explanation would be welcomed. In particular, what is precisely required to reopen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Maclaurin expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}-1$ is alternating, you have, for $x\geq 0$
$$
1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}\leq \sqrt{1+x}\leq 1+\frac{x}{2}
$$
Insert $x=t^n$, integrate, and you will get stronger inequalities than the ones you are asked to prove.

Comment: (+1) I've used this same inequality elsewhere; it is quite useful. The easiest way to verify it is to square all three terms.